# unresolved external symbol with template implementation on VS2010

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, templates, boost-asio, shared-ptr

i just built a template implementation of my boost network.

here is my template class who is calling my network class :

```
AbstractNetwork.hpp :

#include "Network.hpp"

template <typename T, typename R, typename S, typename A>
class       AbstractNetwork
{
private:
    T       connection;

public:
AbstractNetwork(A acceptor)
{
    connection = T::create(acceptor);
}

void write(const R msg)
{
    connection->Swrite(msg);
}

R read(void)
{
    connection->Sread();
    return (connection->getIdata());
}

S getSocket(void)
{
    return (connection->getSocket());
}

void close(void)
{
    connection->close();
}
};
```

and this is my network class who is working with a `boost::tcp::socket` :

```
Network.hpp

class       Network : public boost::enable_shared_from_this<Network>
{
private:
    tcp::socket                     socket;
    std::vector<char>               Idata;
    char                            Iheader[MYINT];
    bool                            readHeader;
    void                            endRead(const error_code& error, size_t nbytes);
    void                            endWrite(const error_code &error);
    size_t                          Isize;

public:
    typedef boost::shared_ptr<Network> ptr;

    Network(io_service &);
    ~Network();
    void                close(void);
    void                Sread(void);
    void                Swrite(Commande *);
    tcp::socket&        getSocket(void);
    Commande*           getIdata(void);
    std::string         convertHeader(void);
    static ptr          create(io_service &);
};
```

i don't give all of function's code because it's too long and i'm sure it works.

When i build this project i have this following error under VS2010 ultimate :

```
error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: void __thiscall AbstractNetwork<class boost::shared_ptr<class Network>,struct Commande *,class boost::asio::basic_stream_socket<class boost::asio::ip::tcp,class boost::asio::stream_socket_service<class boost::asio::ip::tcp> > &,class boost::asio::io_service &>::close(void)"

error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: void __thiscall AbstractNetwork<class boost::shared_ptr<class Network>,struct Commande *,class boost::asio::basic_stream_socket<class boost::asio::ip::tcp,class boost::asio::stream_socket_service<class boost::asio::ip::tcp> > &,class boost::asio::io_service &>::write(struct Commande * const)"

error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: class boost::asio::basic_stream_socket<class boost::asio::ip::tcp,class boost::asio::stream_socket_service<class boost::asio::ip::tcp> > & __thiscall AbstractNetwork<class boost::shared_ptr<class Network>,struct Commande *,class boost::asio::basic_stream_socket<class boost::asio::ip::tcp,class boost::asio::stream_socket_service<classboost::asio::ip::tcp> > &,class boost::asio::io_service &>::getSocket(void)"

error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: __thiscall AbstractNetwork<class boost::shared_ptr<class Network>,struct Commande *,class boost::asio::basic_stream_socket<class boost::asio::ip::tcp,class boost::asio::stream_socket_service<class boost::asio::ip::tcp> > &,class boost::asio::io_service &>::AbstractNetwork<class boost::shared_ptr<class Network>,struct Commande *,classboost::asio::basic_stream_socket<class boost::asio::ip::tcp,class boost::asio::stream_socket_service<class boost::asio::ip::tcp> > &,class boost::asio::io_service &>(class boost::asio::io_service &)
```

it's long, but i want to give you all of these error because i think the problem come to my template type. so i think my problem come to AbstractNetwork.hpp but i can't find this.

Did you have any idea about that ?

Comment: Did you write a Network.cpp source code file with the implementations of the methods?  Did you add it to your project?  The linker errors say you didn't.

Comment: yeah yeah, i have a Network.cpp in my projet, (i didn't give this because it's too long) and i'm sure he is with my project, because i written and tested this before added my AbstractNetwork

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fix your class. You don't need to repeat the template for each class member function, they're part of the template class already.

```
template <typename T, typename R, typename S, typename A>
class       AbstractNetwork
{
private:
    T       connection;

public:
AbstractNetwork(A acceptor)
{
    this->connection = T::create(acceptor);
}

void write(const R msg)
{
    this->connection->Swrite(msg);
}

read(void)
{
    this->connection->Sread();
    return (this->connection->getIdata());
}

getSocket(void)
{
    return (this->connection->getSocket());
}

close(void)
{
    this->close(); //  <<--- is this a mistake?
    //Probably you wanted this->connection->close();
}

};
```

Apart from the apparent typo in `close`, you also don't need to use `this` everywhere, its redundant and makes the code look messier.

Comment: yeah yeah it's a mistake sorry. i am doing these corrections.

Comment: now i have these error : `error C2039: 'create' : is not a member of 'boost::shared_ptr<T>'` and `error C3861: 'create': identifier not found`

Comment: You're passing a class as `T` that doesn't implement the interface you expect (`static T::create`). Fix that. I'm glad your original problem has been resolved though.

Comment: do you mean to put `connection = static T::create(acceptor);` ?

Comment: @Yumino - you should open a new question, and post the relevant code there, so that you could get a reasonably reliable answer. What I'm saying is that the class you pass as `T` **doesn't have** a static member called `create`. I have no idea which class it is and what it does have, so I don't know how you should fix it. It is entirely unrelated to the question I was answering here.

Comment: ok problem solved ! thank for your help ! i just added a new template who is representing my Network class. So i put `connection = TemplateNetwork::create(acceptor)` with `TemplateNetwork` = `Network`. thanks :)